# How to show the top 3 business in sql?

Tags: php, sql, forms

Alright so i need to post the top 3 business categories with the top searches. I've tried the advice provided to be online:

```
$sql = "select search, city, business, count(*)
from vendor
group by category = 'Beauty Salon'
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 3 rows only";
```

I've tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT search, city, business, 
COUNT(*) AS total FROM vendor 
WHERE category = 'Beauty Salon' GROUP BY ASC LIMIT 3";
```

I've had others but to be honest I've tried it in so many ways i can't remember the sources.

I hope you can help me with this. Thank you!

Here is the full code i have been trying maybe it has nothing to do with the `sql`, but what comes afterwards.

```
 <?php
include '../s.php';
$sql = "SELECT search, city, business, COUNT(*) AS total FROM vendor WHERE category = 'Beauty Salon' GROUP BY ASC LIMIT 3";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())     
    { ?>

    <table class="demo">
          <thead>
          <tr class="titledemo" align="left">
              <th width="25%">Ranking</th>
              <th width="25%">Business</th>
              <th width="25%">Searches</th>
              <th width="25%">Category</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>

<? echo "<strong>" . $row["business"]. "<br></strong>";?>

               </td>


              <td>
              <? echo "" . $row["search"]. "<br>";
            ?>
              </td>
              <td>
             <? echo "" . $row["city"]. "<br>"; ?>
              </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
        <?  
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

**NOTE**: when it did show before it would **not** align the rows from the top the least. It is showing *100, 200, 300* and not *300, 200, 100*. I do believe that it is grabbing the top to lest by the date it was inserted because that is how the numbers are set in my database. I didn't understand since I've tried `DESC` and `ASC` and none showed what i needed. It should be based on **search** since that's the number amount of searches for each company.

Comment: "SQL" isn't sufficient to inform us which syntax applies to your question. MySQL uses a syntax that differs to MS SQL Server and that differs to Oracle and so on, but each of those databases can claim to use SQL. Please, for future questions, tell us which database(s) you need to the solution for.

Comment: Oh goodness thank you, no wonder i had it marked down. I will definitely do that next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `subquery` first before limiting your results.

```
select * from (select search, city, business, count(*) ct
from vendor
where category = 'Beauty Salon'
group by search, city, business) t
order by ct asc
limit 3
```

Comment: Thank you, at first it didn't work but i had to change a word that was misspelled by me when typing it down and wala it came out. Although i changed the _ASC_ AND _DESC_ and the row stays the same. It doesn't change up the top 3 why would that be

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
SELECT search, city, business, 
COUNT(*) AS total FROM vendor 
WHERE category = 'Beauty Salon' and ROWNUM <=3

Answer (score 0):

try "TOP 3" after SELECT.

SELECT TOP 3 search, city, business
FROM vendor
GROUP BY category = 'Beauty Salon'